# Vue 3 modal is always open when I use v-model

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vuetify.js, v-model

I want to implement common modal function using 'v-model'.
My codes are like this below:
Actually, the function does work(it shows alert messages) but dialogs which have 'v-model' pop up continuosly even they are 'false'.
Please help me..T_T

```
<template>
      <v-dialog  v-model="modals.add_directory">
         test dialog
      </v-dialog>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>

const modals = {
          add_directory: ref(false),
          add_lvm: ref(false),
          add_lvmthin: ref(false),
          add_nfs: ref(false),
          add_smbcifs: ref(false),
          add_cephfs: ref(false),
          add_rbd: ref(false),
          add_zfs: ref(false),
};

const open_modal = (modalName) => {
    alert(modals[modalName].value);
    modals[modalName].value = !modals[modalName].value;
};

</script>
```

Comment: Instead of using `const modals = { foo: ref(false), bar: ref(false) }` you can use `const modals = reactive({ foo: false, bar: false })`. The advantage is you no longer need to use `.value` in script. `modals.foo` is reactive and doesn't need `.value`. Also, the problem with your code is that `modals` object itself is not reactive, so Vue has no way of knowing when you change one of its properties, even if that property is reactive.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a somewhat irritating behavior of Vue, where refs in the template are not unwrapped when they come from an array or object (see [this bug](https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/737) for reference). You will have to unwrap it yourself, i.e. write `modals.add_directory.value`:

```html
<v-dialog  v-model="modals.add_directory.value">
  ...
</v-dialog>
```

You can see it working like that in the snippet:

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify
const vuetify = createVuetify()
const app = {
  setup(){
    const modals = {
      addDirectory: ref(false),
    };
    
    const openModal = (modalName) => {
      modals[modalName].value = !modals[modalName].value;
    };

    return { openModal, modals }
  }

}
createApp(app).use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.8/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.8/dist/vuetify-labs.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
    
      <v-dialog v-model="modals.addDirectory.value">
        <v-card>
          <v-card-title>
            The add directory dialog 
          </v-card-title>
        </v-card>
      </v-dialog>

      <v-btn @click="openModal('addDirectory')" class="ma-4">
        add directory
      </v-btn>

    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.8/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.8/dist/vuetify-labs.js"></script>
```

---

Alternatively, you could use `reactive`, which does not have this limitation:

```
    const modals = reactive({
      addDirectory: false,
    });
    
    const openModal = (modalName) => {
      modals[modalName] = !modals[modalName];
    };
```

```js
const { createApp, reactive } = Vue;
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify
const vuetify = createVuetify()
const app = {
  setup(){
    const modals = reactive({
      addDirectory: false,
    });
    
    const openModal = (modalName) => {
      modals[modalName] = !modals[modalName];
    };

    return { openModal, modals }
  }

}
createApp(app).use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.8/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.8/dist/vuetify-labs.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
    
      <v-dialog v-model="modals.addDirectory">
        <v-card>
          <v-card-title>
            The add directory dialog 
          </v-card-title>
        </v-card>
      </v-dialog>

      <v-btn @click="openModal('addDirectory')" class="ma-4">
        add directory
      </v-btn>

    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.8/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.8/dist/vuetify-labs.js"></script>
```

Does that work for you?